How to configure a Hyper-V Gen2 VM to boot from file?
I have two VMs in Hyper-V on Windows 11 Pro.
They are both gen2 VMs with Secure Boot disabled.
One of them, debian-test01, I installed from the Debian DVD ISO.
The other, import-test01, is a VHDX file I am trying to import. It also contains a Debian image.
The debian-test01 VM is configured to boot from file (the EFI shim).
The import-test01 VM is configured to boot from the VHDX file.
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VMFirmware -VMName debian-test01

VMName        SecureBoot SecureBootTemplate   PreferredNetworkBootProtocol BootOrder
------        ---------- ------------------   ---------------------------- ---------
debian-test01 Off        OpenSourceShieldedVM IPv4                         {File, Drive, Network, Drive}


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VMFirmware -VMName import-test01

VMName        SecureBoot SecureBootTemplate   PreferredNetworkBootProtocol BootOrder
------        ---------- ------------------   ---------------------------- ---------
import-test01 Off        OpenSourceShieldedVM IPv4                         {Drive, Network}


PS C:\Windows\system32>

I've looked in the built-in and online help for Set-VMFirmware and I don't see anything about adding File to the boot order.
What black magic is this?
